# In C Programming, How do I use a loop to ask user if they want to continue?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am a 1st year Computer Science student, currently taking intro to Programming. We are learning the C Programming language and I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly input a loop at the end of my code to ask the user if they want to continue or not.

This simple assignment asks to develop a program that will determine an employee's gross pay (including an "if" statement to determine overtime). As you'll see in my code, I think I've done so correctly. The assignment goes on to state that at the end of my program I should use a loop to ask the user if they want to continue.

In class, we went over For loops, and While loops, but I am a little lost on how to implement this feature correctly.

I initially tried doing something like...

```
printf("Would you like to continue? (1 = Yes, 2 = No) \n" );
scanf("%i", _____ ); While (_____ == 'y' || ______ == 'Y') {
}
```

But not sure what to declare for the input (scanf) or what to put in the while loop. Please help. Its my spring break and no campus tutoring is around. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    double totalHours, rate, grossPay, overTime, overTimepay, otHours, grossPaywithOT;

    //1. I began by asking user for total hours & getting input
    printf("Enter your total hours worked : \n");
    scanf("%lf", &totalHours);

    //Now I'm using a selection statement to determine pay for overtime hours
    if (totalHours > 40) {
        //a. Inform user they have overtime hours
        printf("You worked over 40 hours this period. \n");

        //b. Ask how many hours over 40 they worked
        printf("How many hours over 40 did you work? : \n");
        scanf("%lf", &otHours);

        //c. Ask the user for hourly rate
        printf("What is your hourly rate? : \n");
        scanf("%lf", &rate);

        //d. Overtime Rate Calculation & Gross Pay Calculation
        grossPay = totalHours * rate;
        overTime = 1.5 * rate;
        overTimepay = otHours * overTime;
        grossPaywithOT = overTimepay + grossPay;

        //e. Display overtime pay and Gross Pay
        printf("Your overtime pay is %.02lf \n", overTimepay);
        printf("Your total Gross Pay including overtime is %.02lf \n", grossPaywithOT);
    } else {
        //2. Ask the user for hourly rate
        printf("What is your hourly rate? : \n");

        //3. User input for hourly rate
        scanf("%lf", &rate);

        //4. Gross Pay Calculation
        grossPay = totalHours * rate;

        //5. Display grossPay
        printf("Your Gross Pay is %.02lf \n", grossPay);
    }
}
```

Comment: printf("Would you like to continue? (1 = Yes, 2 = No) \n" );  scanf("%i", _____ );  While (_____ == 'y' || ______ == 'Y') {      // logic      printf("Would you like to continue? (1 = Yes, 2 = No) \n" );  scanf("%i", _____ );  }.       You need to ask if the user wants to continue again whilst in the loop or you will be stuck in a infinite loop. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

```
char loop='y';
while(loop == 'y') {

    //Do your stuff here

    printf("do you want to loop? (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c", &loop);
    if(loop != 'y')
        loop='n';
}
```

/A

Comment: Thanks! This helped a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
    // loop until they decide to stop

    // put the code to do your normal stuff here

    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        // loop until they input a 1 or 2
        printf("\nWould you like to continue? (1 = Yes, 2 = No) \n" );
        scanf("%i", &i);
    } while ((i != 1) && (i != 2));

} while (i == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` doesn't write into variables, but into memory addresses. 
So, in your `_____`code you should write a pointer to a memory address. A couple of examples:

```
int * intPointer;
scanf("%i", intPointer);
```

Or:

```
int integer;
scanf("%i", &integer);
```

Note that you typed `"%i"` in the formatting string. `%i` tells `scanf()` that the string typed by the user should be parsed as an integer. You want to read it as a character. C formatting functions (that's what the final **f** in `scanf()` means use `%c`for characters.